# Prevent parent element scroll, when click on anchor tag in iFrame

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on the anchor tag, only iframe contents need to scroll to a particular element, not the parent window.

I have gone through multiple references but couldn't find a proper solution.

Here is the reproducible [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/iframe-scrolling-issue-497ooq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Bravo you can check the code which I mentioned in the above example.

Comment: I am getting this issue in the chrome browser, but in firefox, it works fine.

Comment: Can we handle this window scrolling issue when clicking on the anchor tag in the chrome browser?

Comment: **NOTE: this is a CHROME ONLY issue**